# Is there any NGO based in Russia that didn't get listed as a foreign agent while accepting donation from abroad?

Tags: russian-federation, foreign-interference, ngos

> **In 2013 the Levada Center reported it received from 1.5% to 3% of its
> total budget from abroad.[11] It was issued with a public warning that
> it would be eligible for listing as a 'foreign agent' under the
> recently passed Russian foreign agent law.[11]** Levada said it
> suspended foreign funding in 2013.[12] After the Levada Center on 1
> September 2016 published the results of a poll that had found a
> significant decline in support for the ruling United Russia party, the
> Russian Justice declared that the pollster was "performing the
> functions of a foreign agent".[13][14] This barred it from work on the
> upcoming election.[15][12][16] Levada's director stated that the
> designation may mean that Levada would be unable to continue its work
> as a pollster.[17] "This manifests the increase in internal
> repressions carried out by the country's leadership," the center's
> director, Lev Gudkov, had told TV Rain, the New York Times reported,
> "If they won't cancel this decision, it will mean that the Levada
> Center will have to stop working, because you cannot conduct polls
> with such a stigma put on you."[14]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levada_Center

Is there any NGO based in Russia that didn't get listed as a foreign agent while accepting donation from abroad? The government of Russia warned the Levada Center that it would be eligible for listiing as a foreign agent if it kept receiving money from abroad. I was wondering if there's any NGO as of now that wasn't listed as a foreign agent in Russia while accepting donation from abroad.

Comment: somewhat relevant, there seems to be no threshold for the amount https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/46864/what-are-the-thresholds-for-an-organization-to-be-declared-a-foreign-agent-in-ru